# Selenium Webdriver try/catch with more elements

Tags: java, selenium

is it possible to use try/catch with more than one elements?
Like...

```
 try {
        (driver.findElements(By.xpath("xyz1"))).size() !=0;
    or
        (driver.findElements(By.xpath("xyz2"))).size() !=0;
     }
```

It is possible that only xyz1 exist or xyz1 and xyz2. Or none of them. 
If xyz1 or xyz1 & xyz2 exist, then this elements should be clicked.

Comment: Do you mean falling back to the second `findElement` if the first one throws an exception? Did you mean to have two different XPaths in the two expressions?

Comment: Your question is completely unclear, and to a certain extent - wrong! Method `findElement` returns a `WebElement` instance, which does not have method `size`. You can use method `findElements` instead, which returns a `List<WebElement>` instance. But this method does not throw an exception, so there is no need to use a `try/catch` clause.

Comment: ok. I'll edit the question. ;)

Comment: Again - you don't need to call `findElements` inside a `try/catch` clause. It does not throw an exception!!! If no elements are found, it returns a list with no elements (`size() == 0`).

Comment: You are talking about if statement?

Comment: Thanks barak! you helped me alot. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("xyz1"))).size() !=0)

    clickXyz1Elements();

else if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("xyz2"))).size() !=0)

    clickXyz2Elements();
```